# A question related to injective envelope for a system of DGA's

Tags: gn.general-topology, equivariant-homotopy, rational-homotopy-theory

I was trying to read Fine and Triantafillou's paper "On the equivariant formality of Kahler manifolds with finite group action".

They have defined the enlargement at $H$ of a system of DGA's $A$, as

$I_H(A)(G/K)= A(G/K) \otimes \underline{A}_H(G/K)$ for $K$ proper subgroup of a conjugate of $H$ and

$=A(G/K)$ otherwise, here $\underline{A}_H$ is acyclic obtained by suspension trick.

Is there any typo or am I missing something? While considering the level $G/H$, the term $I_H(A)(G/H)$ is just same as $A(G/H)$ so nothing is added in this level?

Thanks in advance!!